# user-defined conversion cannot use static_cast in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, enable-if

I am trying to solve some problems with **Eigen**. In the process, I found that **static_cast** and **user-defined conversion** conflict, maybe the problem caused by **std::enable_if**?

Here is basically what I tried:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Vector2
{
public:
    operator Eigen::Vector2d ()
    {   
        return data;
    }   
private:
    Eigen::Vector2d data;
};

class Box2
{
public:
    void Extend(const Vector2 & a)  
    {   
        data.extend( static_cast<Eigen::Vector2d>(a) );     // error, but why?
    }   
private:
    Eigen::AlignedBox2d data;   
};

int main()
{
    Vector2 a;
    Eigen::Vector2d b = a;      // ok, implicit conversion
    return 0;   
}
```

`g++ -std=c++11`outputs a lot of error logs, this is the last part:

```
eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:863:30: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h: In substitution of ‘template<class T> void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_init1(const Index&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<((((((! Eigen::internal::is_same<long int, typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>::value) && Eigen::internal::is_same<long int, T>::value) && (typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type:: SizeAtCompileTime != Eigen::Dynamic)) && (typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type:: SizeAtCompileTime != 1)) && Eigen::internal::is_convertible<T, typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>::value) && Eigen::internal::is_same<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::XprKind, Eigen::ArrayXpr>::value), T*>::type*) [with T = T; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>] [with T = Vector2]’:
eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:296:33:   required from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T&) [with T = Vector2; _Scalar = double; int _Rows = 2; int _Cols = 1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = 2; int _MaxCols = 1]’
test.cpp:21:52:   required from here
eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:863:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Eigen::internal::enable_if<false, Vector2*>’
In file included from eigen/eigen/Eigen/Core:364:0,
                 from eigen/eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from eigen/eigen/Eigen/Eigen:1,
                 from test.cpp:2:
eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:162:50: error: declaration of ‘struct Eigen::internal::enable_if<false, Vector2*>’
 template<bool Condition, typename T=void> struct enable_if;
                                                  ^
```

It seems like the issue of **enable_if**, I wonder why **static_cast** doesn't work. Is there a way to solve this problem without modifying Eigen? It is ok to do this now:

```
void Extend(Vector2 a)  
{   
    Eigen::Vector2d b = a;
    data.extend( b );    
}
```

But it's too ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems like the issue of `enable_if`, I wonder why `static_cast` doesn't
>   work.

This has nothing to do with the `static_cast` itself. The error is generated because `Vector2`'s `operator Eigen::Vector2d ()` isn't defined for `const` objects and since your `Box2::Extend()` takes a `const Vector2& a`, the appropriate casting isn't defined for that line in the code. Add a `const` version of `Vector2`'s *user defined casting* to `Eigen::Vector2d` to make it both compile and keep the [*const-correctness*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) of the code:

```
const operator Eigen::Vector2d () const
{   
    return data;
}
```

Now the usage is working like you wanted:

```
int main()
{
    Vector2 a;
    Eigen::Vector2d b = a;    // ok, implicit conversion

    Box2 boxy;
    boxy.Extend(a);           // also ok, implicit conversion inside, from a const&

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist Thank you! I followed your solution and solved it. C++ compilation error logs often mislead me. Also thank others here.

Comment: @sfire Note that on second thought, I've edited to make it clear that the correct solution is *to add* another version of the casting operator, not make due with just changing the existing one.

Comment: Okay, I know. Thanks for your information about const correctness.